# Qual é uma palavra para descrever o atributo de ser destro ou canhoto?

Tags: vocabulário

Em português, ao meu entendimento:

**Destro(a)** - Quem escreve (ou é dominante) com a mão direita

**Canhoto(a)** - Quem escreve (ou é dominante) com a mão esquerda

**Ambidestro(a)** - Quem escreve (ou é dominante) com as duas mãos

Usando um exemplo simples, tem *azul*, *verde*, e *vermelho*, mas todos são descritos sob o atributo de ***cor***.

Usando outro exemplo, ambos *macho* e *fêmea* são o ***gênero*** de uma pessoa.

Qual seria a palavra/frase que descreve esse atributo?

<sub>Me refiro também a [essa pergunta no English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241616/male-female-is-to-gender-as-left-handed-right-handed-is-to).</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Posso estar equivocado, mas acredito que a palavra seja

### Lateralidade

> Substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Qualidade ou condição do que é lateral.
> 2. Predomínio ou maior eficiência de um dos lados do corpo, de um entre dois membros simétricos ou de um dos hemisférios cerebrais, quanto a certa atividade ou função.

Acredito que seja isto, pois quem usa a mão direita geralmente usa o lado direito do corpo, assim como quem usa a mão esquerda também usa o lado esquerdo do corpo ou tem melhor domínio sobre este lado.

### O que é lateralidade

Lateralidade é a predisposição à utilização preferencial de um dos lados do corpo, em três níveis: mão, olho e pé. Segundo Le Boulch, a preferência pela utilização de um dos lados do corpo ocorre devido à dominância de um dos hemisférios cerebrais.

Os movimentos bilaterais envolvem o uso de ambos os lados de modo simultâneo e paralelo, como por exemplo pegar um bola com as duas mãos; já os movimentos unilaterais envolvem o uso de apenas um lado do corpo, como por exemplo bater com a mão num alvo.

Esta capacidade é de grande importância para a formação de conceitos complexos como o de espaço.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateralidade

Comment: Opa! Gostei dessa palavra, é mais fácil do q inglês rsrs

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar estranhamente além das palavras que vi nas respostas do english.SE, notei que existe uma palavra equivalente ao **lateralidade** no inglês, que seria **laterality**. [editado] Usei o google tradutor pra traduzir a palavra **handedness** e a tradução foi **lateralidade**, então realmente no Português está parece a mais correta :)

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar estou curioso, em que contexto você pretende usar essa palavra? Tem uma frase de exemplo?